# Is there any tool to calculate the Encounter XP in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, tool-recommendation

I've seen online tools that make random encounters for you as the donjon's one.

What I need is a tool where I can select the party level and the monsters and it will tell me if it's an easy or hard encounter since there are many things that change the way you calculate the XP of a combat (like the amount of enemies, for example).

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question. If you're looking to just look at the levels and the monsters and see the difficulty of that encounter, the DMG for 5e (even the free version you can download) has a really convenient table for determining that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one I personaly use is this one: [Kobold Fight Club](http://kobold.club/fight/#/encounter-builder)

Works well for my needs, can be used to generate a random encounter for your party, only downside I found is you can't seem to input levels if your party is of different levels.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for.
Yes, it's sad you can't make a party of different level adventurers, but oh, well, all the rest makes it awesome.

Answer (score 9):

The search term that I used on google was [`Encounter build dungeons 5e`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Encounter+build+dungeons+5e), and the top two results appeared to match what you need:

1. Dave Holley's [Dungeons & Dragons 5th Edition Encounter Calculator](http://dhmholley.co.uk/encounter-calculator-5th/)

and:

2. Goblinist RPG Tools' [D&D 5th Edition Random Encounter Generator](http://tools.goblinist.com/5enc)

The second has a very nice interface, and as the last update was Dec. 12, 2014 so it appears to be actively maintained and updated. It will allow you to build a random encounter and it will create it and show you the XP, while the first allows you to enter in a pre-existing encounter. Either/both should be able to do what you would like.

Comment: I'm aware of those two, but thanks.

I'm looking for a tool that let's me also select the monsters, not only their CR.

Answer (score 4):

Shameless plug for my own excel tool:

[Posted at ENWorld](http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=1178)

Its pretty simple, so the others may have a better layout for what you want. But mine does custom party (members of varying levels) and even large or small party size changes. Hope it helps!